# IntelliJ IDEA sbt shell plugins break dependencies

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, dependencies, sbt, intellij-plugin

I have an outdated Play project that uses some dependencies of older versions.
When I use the `compile` task in the `idea sbt shell` it fails with error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: spray.json.JsonParser$.apply(Ljava/lang/String;)Lspray/json/JsValue;
  at com.typesafe.sbt.jse.SbtJsTask$$anonfun$com$typesafe$sbt$jse$SbtJsTask$$executeJsOnEngine$1$$anonfun$4.apply(SbtJsTask.scala:190)
  at com.typesafe.sbt.jse.SbtJsTask$$anonfun$com$typesafe$sbt$jse$SbtJsTask$$executeJsOnEngine$1$$anonfun$4.apply(SbtJsTask.scala:181)
```

The analysis of the problem gave the answer

```
[warn]   * io.spray:spray-json_2.10:1.3.6 is selected over 1.2.6
[warn]       +- org.jetbrains.scala:scala-compiler-indices-protocol_2.10:1.0.14 (depends on 1.3.6)
```

IntelliJ IDEA mixes plugins for a project using

```
[info] Loading global plugins from ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins
```

~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/idea.sbt

```
if (java.lang.System.getProperty("idea.runid", "false") == "2023.1.0") scala.collection.Seq(
resolvers += Resolver.file("Scala Plugin Bundled Repository",file(raw"~/.local/share/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.2/Scala/repo"))(Resolver.mavenStylePatterns),
addSbtPlugin("org.jetbrains.scala" % "sbt-structure-extractor" % "2023.1.0"),
addSbtPlugin("org.jetbrains.scala" % "sbt-idea-shell" % "2021.1.0"),
addSbtPlugin("org.jetbrains.scala" % "sbt-idea-compiler-indices" % "1.0.14")
) else scala.collection.Seq.empty
```

Additional plugins have more recent dependencies. In particular, spray-json in which JsonParser(s: String) was cut in 1.3.6, and LESS calls it when compiling.

[spray-json 1.2.6](https://github.com/spray/spray-json/blob/f5937815e4eab31853d5f5e65b0dda8fb6b81e15/src/main/scala/spray/json/JsonParser.scala#L109C3-L109C61)

[spray-json 1.3.6](https://github.com/spray/spray-json/blob/d0008f56bc07f7b5cd446b83184949155d40a7ff/src/main/scala/spray/json/JsonParser.scala#L29)

[compile error](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-js-engine/blob/d5e2dda4b3bbcea47ac87bfa13f0173bffbde863/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/jse/SbtJsTask.scala#L190)

Is there a way to force the plugin to use its dependency, and sbt forbid raising the dependency version automatically? How can you get out of this situation?